# PD.Read_Excel reads columns in as index?

Tags: pandas, python-2.7, dataframe

**I don't believe this question is a duplicate as the question you have linked references how to use excel column labels as column labels for the dataframe.  I am not asking that, I am asking why columns are being read into the index?**

I am using the read_excel pandas method to bring excel sheets into python as a dataframe.  However when I execute code like the following:

```
pd.read_excel(df)
```

it produces the following output:

```
df.columns
Index([u'Column1', u'Column2', u'Column3'], dtype='object')
```

Why does read_excel method appear to be importing my columns in as an index?  How do I stop this from happening?  I have tried to use code like this:

```
pd.read_excel(df,index_col=0)
```

However that produces the following output:

```
df.columns
Index([u'Column2', u'Column3'], dtype='object')
```

Comment: Do you need `pd.read_excel(df,header=None)` ?

Comment: your excel first row is imported as the dataframe columns index.

Comment: Am I misinterpreting this line then: "Index([u'Column2', u'Column3'], dtype='object')" -> I am reading this as "the index of this dataframe is column2, column3)?